# What Should the Limits On the Camera's Pitch Be?

Tags: camera, angles

What should I be using as the limit to how much a camera can pitch in a first person video game? I'm assuming most video games use around the same value - so if I can use that value in my game, it will feel more natural to the user, since they are already used to such limits.

For example, let's say straight up is +90 degrees, straight down -90 degrees, and straight is 0 degrees. What's the min/max angle most first person games would impose?

Edit: Since this question is put on hold as opinion based, let me try to re-word it so it's more appropriate:

Is there a standard limit on the pitch? If so, what is it? If not, what should I keep in mind when deciding the limit for this?

Comment: If you are actually using Euler angles to represent your pitch, then you ***definitely*** want to avoid +/- 90 degrees. If you try to interpolate your pitch between said orientation and another point you may completely invert your camera.

Comment: I'm not actually using -/+90, I'm using radians, just for the sake of the question, +/-90 is simpler.

Comment: Radians will not make a difference, there is a singularity that occurs at +/- 90 degrees or pi/2. If your camera is allowed to move beyond that pitch you will wind up with "gimbal lock" and the orientation may flip depending on how you update it.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman if you force the Right vector to remain horizontal (only have pivot and pitch, without roll) then you avoid the gimbal lock by removing a degree freedom

Comment: A lot of modern FPS games actually use roll. And not just the ones that have vehicle piloting in them; BF4 uses it for instance while in first-person perspective standing on an aircraft carrier as it rolls with the waves.

Comment: There's no roll in my game, the camera is only rotated on the Y and X axis.

Comment: I think this question is too opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FPS cameras, there is no technical reason why the pitch needs to be smaller than +/- 90 degrees; the reasons for limiting it are purely gameplay-related, and it's obvious if you've encountered it.

When you are looking straight up or down, attempting to look left or right will not move your reticle with respect to the game world, instead you simply rotate on the spot. This makes it difficult to track moving targets that are directly above or below you, amongst other issues. Some games impose a pitch limit to address this issue, but most games avoid this issue altogether using smarter level design, and I think you should do this too.

Try to avoid situations that would require your player to look far up or down, such as:

- Avoid large vertical spaces, such as high towers, atriums etc. Prefer stairs, ramps and enclosed lifts to ladders or holes.
- If you cannot avoid a large vertical space, try to limit the vertical size of fields of view. For example, design watchtowers with shorter windows such that defenders can only see so far up or down. Consider this sketch of a watchtower that can only view so far down:

[image: watchtower example]

- Failing that, try to provide plenty of visual cues that help the player orient, to subtly remind them that they are looking up or down and to expect different results when looking left/right. Perfectly vertical or horizontal lines are great. For example, the skyscrapers in this picture lets you know that you are looking directly up, at an otherwise reference-free sky:

[image: skyscrapers viewed directly up]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard value.  Some games let you go all the way to 90 degrees; some cut you off at somewhere around 85 degrees, I'd guess.  I don't think the precise value is a big deal.

Regarding the point about Euler angles, gimbal lock, etc. - there's actually no particular reason to limit the pitch to strictly less than 90 degrees, aside from the fact that it's disorienting to turn the camera upside down.  In a first-person game you typically only control pitch and yaw, not roll, so you actually don't have any gimbal lock issue with the first-person camera itself.

If you want to animate in and out of the first-person camera then that should be done with quaternions, as usual when animating.  In other words, convert the current first-person camera orientation to a quat and then animate/blend from there.  However I think this is pretty unusual.  Most first-person games don't attempt to blend smoothly between the first-person perspective and cutscene cameras.